# How to use help files of mega software

Tags: command-line, software-installation

I am going to work with [mega software](http://www.megasoftware.net/home) for Ubuntu linux. Mega software manual, quick-start tuturial has been copied to `/usr/share/megacc` along with example data files and a `chm` file containing the help documentation for the GUI version of mega. I need to use them.

But, when I open terminal in folder where I installed mega and write `/usr/share/megacc` the answer shown to me is

> bash: /usr/share/megacc: is a directory

I don't know how to solve this problem. Please help me.

Note: [MegaSoftware](http://www.megasoftware.net/home) is a software for analyzing DNA and protein sequence data from species and populations

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly? a directory name is not a command, if you want to *change to* the directory, use `cd /usr/share/megacc`. If you want to do something else, [edit] your question to clearly state what.

Comment: Your question has been reopened and answered. Check if that works

Answer (score 2):

`/usr/share/megacc` is a directory, not a command. That's why you can't run it. But, you can go to that directory with the command

```
cd /usr/share/megacc
```

or just using

```
nautilus /usr/share/megacc
```

command in a terminal.

If you want to open the chm file there, you need to first install a chm reader. xchm is a good option. Install it with

```
sudo apt install xchm
```

The help chm file's name is `Mega7.chm`. If you want to read that manual, you need to do

```
xchm /usr/share/megacc/Mega7.chm
```

There are pdf documents and examples sets. Since you're going to use it, I recommend linking them in your home directory. You can do so by using these command in a terminal

```
ln -s /usr/share/megacc/Mega7.chm ~/
ln -s /usr/share/megacc/Examples ~/
ln -s /usr/share/megacc/MEGA7-CC-User-Manual.pdf ~/
```

Hope that helps.